# Why use media query type "all" when it's implied?

Tags: css, media-queries

I recently noticed that I have been using `all` in every `@media` query rule and I can't figure out why I did that.

I've searched the web and I see that most `@media` rule examples on the web use some format like this `@media all and (some other condition...)`, why is there media type `all` when it's already implied if no media type is specified?
Is it perhaps some older browser compatibility issue?

I guess what I'm really asking is why is it common practice to use media type `all` when there is no need for it?

Comment: No particular reason that I can see other than that it's a common convention to include the media type in a media query. The only browser compatibility issue is that some old browsers may attempt to parse media queries as just their media types, in which case one would use `only all and ...` to stop that happening. Not in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Media Queries W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries):

> ‘all’ is used to indicate that the style sheet applies to all media types.
>
> ...
>
> A shorthand syntax is offered for media queries that apply to all media types; the keyword ‘all’ can be left out (along with the trailing ‘and’). I.e. if the media type is not explicitly given it is ‘all’.

The use of the words *to indicate* in the first quoted sentence sound to me like `all` by itself can be used purely for presentational purposes.

There are a few parts where `all` is used for a specific purpose, however. In [section 3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#error-handling) the document mentions:

> **Unknown media features.** User agents are to represent a media query as `"not all"` when one of the specified media features is not known.
>
> **Unknown media feature values.** As with unknown media features, user agents are to represent a media query as `"not all"` when one of the specified media feature values is not known.

Malformed media queries default to `not all`, as well.

Another example of this, as BoltClock mentioned in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651924/why-use-media-query-type-all-when-its-implied/19653547#comment29180591_19651924) on the question would be the use of `only all`. The keyword `only` is used to hide stylesheets from older user agents. We can test this with the following CSS:

```css
body {
    background: red;
}

@media only all {
    body {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

If we open this in a modern browser, the document's `body` will have a green background. If we open this in an older browser (IE8, for instance), the document's `body` will have a red background.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhn49/1/embedded/result/).

Comment: `all` is also required if you're trying to negate a media query but want to apply it to all media types, e.g. `not all and (color)` would match user agents that don't have a color display regardless of whether they're print, screen, or something else. For some reason, `not (color)` is invalid.