# What's the use for the "only all" media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

I was cleaning up some legacy CSS, and found out several usages of the `@media only all` query without any other conditions, which left me puzzled.

Is there a reason I'm not seeing to use a media query like this instead of no media query at all?

Comment: Alternative duplicate, depending on what your actual question is: [What is the difference between “screen” and “only screen” in media queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries)

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack that allows a query to be applied only in some old browsers (e.g. IE8 and below). You can find more info more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19653547/860478).